# arules package in R , some methods won't work

Tags: r, transactions, rules, arules

I am doing a function that given a transaction x and a set of rules y, if x as a whole is a subset of y then I am interested in it cause I can do a recommendation based on the rules (I am using "Groceries" dataset) I am trying to do this using `%ain%` but as crazy as it seems RStudio is not recognizing it, I will leave you my code and the error it throws.

```
install.packages("arules") 
library(arules) 
myfunction <- function(t,w,z){ 
  lav <- which (t %ain% w,arr.ind=TRUE) 
  lav <- z[lav,] 
  lav <- unique(lav) 
  return (lav) 
} 
data("Groceries") 
x <- list(c("pip fruit","root vegetables","yogurt","soda","fruit/vegetable juice")) 
reglas = apriori(Groceries, parameter=list(supp=0.0006, conf=0.98)) 
t <- as(x,"transactions") 
z <- slot(reglas,"rhs") 
w <- slot(reglas,"lhs") 
inspect(myfunction(t,w,z))
```

and this is the error:

```
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function  'which': Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘%ain%’ for signature ‘"transactions", "itemMatrix"’
```

Comment: is a method from arules package that checks if all elements in x are in y

Comment: Did you load the packages?

Comment: yes, actually w and z are the lhs and the rhs of a set of rules made out of the apriori algorithm

Comment: As far as I understand the `%ain%` function, it "matches the strings in an `character` object against the item labels in an `itemMatrix` object. In your case, you try to match the strings in a  `transactions` object against an `itemMatrix` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all.

> error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function  'which': Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘%ain%’ for signature ‘"transactions", "itemMatrix"’

`?'%ain%'` says `%ain%` is defined as `signature(x = "itemMatrix", table = "character")`.

In your case, your `x` has class 'transactions', not 'itemMatrix'. And your table `w` has class "itemMatrix", not "character".

If you want to see if any of the itemsets in `w` contain any of the items in `t` ('pip fruit', etc), you will have to

```
w %ain% t # not t %ain% w
```

where `t` is a CHARACTER vector (i.e. `x[[1]]` in your example), so you'd have to write something that extracts a character vector from your 'transations' class.

If the opposite direction is actually what you want (`t %ain% w`), you will have to somehow coerce your `t` (class "transactions") into an itemMatrix, and coerce your `w` (class "itemMatrix") into a character vector.

Also, I think you might be misunderstanding what %ain% does: It

> returns a logical vector indicating if a row (itemset) in ‘x’ contains *any* of the items specified in ‘table’.

so the `arr.ind` in the `which` probably has no effect here - the result of `%ain%` is not a matrix but a vector.

Comment: thank you very much for this answer, i am really new to R, but now my algorithm worked, it was totally a messup of types :)

Comment: @RodolfoJoséMiquilarena That's why providing a reproducible example is useful. Please mark this answer as accepted.